# Issues Installing MySQL 5.5 manually on Ubuntu 10.04 server, errors about "/tmp/mysql.sock"

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mysql

I've set up an Ubuntu server and wanted to install MySQL 5.5. I've been following these [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-installation.html) steps.

I have `libaio dev` installed. Everything went fine until I ran

```
bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
```

it outputs the following and keeps the prompt.

```
111130 12:57:44 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/host_name.err'.
```

111130 12:57:44 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data

It runs into an issue and never returns to the shell. The output of `mysqld_safe` is logging to `/usr/local/mysql/data/host_name.err`.

```
    I    /usr/local/mysql/data/loft1551.host_name.err                                           Row 29   Col 1    1:00  Ctrl-K H for help
    111130 12:57:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist: 
    InnoDB: a new database to be created!
    111130 12:57:44  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
    InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
    111130 12:57:45  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
    InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
    InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
    111130 12:57:45  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
    InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
    InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
    InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
    InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
    InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
    InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
    InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created 
    111130 12:57:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
    111130 12:57:47 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 0
    111130 12:57:48 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
    111130 12:57:48 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
    Version: '5.5.17-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

there are already /tmp/mysql.sock in `[mysqld]` and `[client]` so i added under `[mysqld]`

```
datadir         =/usr/local/mysql/data
```

but still getting the same issue
What am i missing here ?

Thanks for reading this and helping out

Answer (score 0):

While it's running I would suggest getting:

```
ps -fLu mysql
```

And I suggest trying to do `strace` on the mysqld_safe process to see what it is waiting on for exit.  It is possible that it is waiting on a child process to return control to exit.